# StackOverflow database collation?

Tags: support, search

What is the collation used for StackOverflow trilogy databases?

The intention of this question is optimize how one can do a search within SO sites.

My guess is that, collation is set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI` but I would like to know if case sensitivity or accents matter or not.

Comment: Does this question belong here or on SO? hmm...

Comment: Here, for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collation is currently set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` - the "why" is lost in antiquity.

We'll probably change it over to a case-insensitive collation at some point, but it's not a concern right now.

However, we're using SQL Server's Full Text Search, which is case-insensitive*, so the database collation shouldn't matter.

<sub>* only place I could find MS saying it's case-insensitive: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx (search for *sensitive*)</sub>